# Probability question about chance of finding an item

Tags: probability

Okay, so I'm trying to help my partner with a question on her university work because I'm a little better at maths than her. I have managed to remember to work out how to get the probability of finding a Hulk (see below) in each of the chocolate shops, I'm just having trouble with then applying that to the amount of eggs bought. The question is as follows:

Peter is collecting Avengers action figures buried in chocolate Easter eggs. He has all the heroes, except for the Incredible Hulk – if he obtains this he will complete his set. Peter somehow managed to obtain the following information: Out of the total 200, 300 and 500 Easter eggs supplied to the three chocolate shops in Peter’s city, 10, 30 and 50 of them contain the Incredible Hulk, respectively. He ended up buying the last 15, 20 and 45 chocolate eggs from these three shops. What is the probability that he completes his collection? Ensure that it is clear to the reader how you arrived at your answer, that is use appropriate notation and explain the steps you are taking to solve the problem. Marks may be deducted if this is not carried out.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that he does *not* complete his collection is easier, we then take the complementary probability to find the answer.

If a shop has $N$ eggs, $h$ of which contain the hulk and we buy $b$ many eggs from them, in order to *not* find a hulk we have to pick $b$ eggs out of the $N-h$ eggs, while the total number of selections is just the number of $b$ out of $N$.

So $P(\text{no hulk}) = \frac{\binom{N-h}{b}}{\binom{N}{b}}$.

To not complete the collection, we have to do this three times (independence, so product rule) and the asked for probability is

$$1 - \frac{\binom{200-10}{15}}{\binom{200}{15}}\frac{\binom{300-30}{20}}{\binom{300}{20}}\frac{\binom{500-50}{45}}{\binom{500}{45}}$$

which turns out to be $0,99964\ldots$, so quite close to $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So (excuse me if I'm being dumb, I haven't studied any of this stuff for about 6 years) by working this out, I can then flip the answer (i.e., for example if the probability he doesn't complete his collection is 0.7, the probability he completes his collection is 0.3)?

Could you please clarify what you mean by this calculation at the end, do we divide 200 - 10 by 15 and then divide this by the answer of 200 / 15 or am I misunderstanding? again, apologies if I'm being an idiot here.

Comment: @JayDee We divide the *binomial coefficient* of $200-10$ over $15$ by the *binomial coefficient* of $200$ over $15$, etc. Study up on those, as the count the number of size $k$ subsets out of $n$ elements. I already "flipped" the answer: the $1-$ part. The product is the chance of not completing.